# R - multiple calls to dplyr::crossing() - can I simplify?

Tags: r, apply, tidyr

I have a piece of code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_ref <- data.frame(factor_1 = "A", factor_2 = "Y", factor_3 = "3")

factor_1_levels <- c("A", "B", "C")
factor_2_levels <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
factor_3_levels <- c("1", "2", "3")

df_ref_1 <- crossing(select(df_ref, -factor_1), factor_1_levels) %>% rename(factor_1 = factor_1_levels)
df_ref_2 <- crossing(select(df_ref, -factor_2), factor_2_levels) %>% rename(factor_2 = factor_2_levels)
df_ref_3 <- crossing(select(df_ref, -factor_3), factor_3_levels) %>% rename(factor_3 = factor_3_levels)
```

You can see I've got 3 factors defined, and I'm doing the exact same thing with each of them. The code does what I need it to do, but it's bad code. In real world examples I might have 200 factors instead, and doing the above 200 times over is obviously very bad indeed. Is there a nice way to code this using one of the `apply()` type functions, or similar?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproductive example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apologies - yes, that would be more helpful I guess. I've edited my posting now to show a simple example.

Comment: Why you store levels independentely? Usualy it should be like this : df_ref <- data.frame(
  factor_1 =factor("A", levels = c("A", "B", "C")), 
  factor_2 = factor("Y", levels = c("X", "Y", "Z")), 
  factor_3 = factor("3", levels = c("1", "2", "3")))

Comment: I need the separate frames for some calls later to the revoScaleR::rxPredict() function. Well...I think I do anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create pairwise combinations of the names into a `list`, then `select` the columns from the 'df_ref' and create the `crossing` from the `list` of 'factor_\d+_levels`objects in`map2`and`rename` the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
lst1 <- combn(rev(names(df_ref)), 2, FUN = function(nm1)
       df_ref %>%
            select(nm1), simplify = FALSE)
imap(mget(ls(pattern = "^factor_\\d+_levels$")), 
        ~ list(.x, .y) ) %>% 
             map2(lst1, ., ~  crossing(.x, !! .y[[2]] := .y[[1]]) %>%
             rename_at(vars(ends_with('levels')), ~ str_remove(., '_levels')))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  factor_3 factor_2 factor_1
#  <fct>    <fct>    <chr>   
#1 3        Y        A       
#2 3        Y        B       
#3 3        Y        C       

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  factor_3 factor_1 factor_2
#  <fct>    <fct>    <chr>   
#1 3        A        X       
#2 3        A        Y       
#3 3        A        Z       

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  factor_2 factor_1 factor_3
#  <fct>    <fct>    <chr>   
#1 Y        A        1       
#2 Y        A        2       
#3 Y        A        3
```